# Background color of roMessageDialog

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku BrightScript, is there any way to change the background color of popup dialogs such as [roMessageDialog](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roMessageDialog) to a dark blue color, instead of the default gray?

It is possible to change the text color through the attributes `DialogBodyText` and `DialogTitleText` in [roAppManager](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roAppManager), but I don't see any way to change the background color.

Setting `ThemeType` to `generic-dark` also appears to have some effect, but only allows switching between light gray and dark gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use roImageCanvas or roScreen to create the pop-up of your choice.

Comment: I am not sure if any source code is available on internet which demonstrates this. But I have created it a lot of times. It works fine for me.

Comment: I experimented with roImageCanvas and that indeed appears the easiest way to achieve this. An [introduction](https://blog.roku.com/developer/2012/09/29/creating-custom-brightscript-uis-with-image-canvas/) is available at the Roku Developer Blog.

Answer (score 2):

Received the following answer at the [Roku developer forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=87670#p494580):

*"No, there is just the standard and the "dark" theme for these. You might consider creating your own pop-up dialog with roImageCanvas."*

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom scene graph dialog.
https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/standard-dialog-framework-nodes/standard-dialog.md